# APEX Trigger to Update Contact Field with Case Number every time new Case is Created

Tags: triggers, salesforce, field, apex

I am trying to create a Salesforce APEX Trigger to update the Contact Field "Last_Case_Number_Solved" with the Case Number assigned, every time a new Case Record is created.

Please help!

I've tried multiple codes and have not yet been successful.

Answer (score 0):

Please, look at this code. Hope this will help you.

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert) {
    Map<Id, String> contactIdToCaseNumberMap = new Map<Id, String>();

    for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
        if (String.isNotBlank(c.ContactId)) {
            contactIdToCaseNumberMap.put(c.ContactId, c.CaseNumber);
        }
    }

    List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Last_Case_Number_Solved__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactIdToCaseNumberMap.keySet()];
    for (Contact cont : contactsToUpdate) {
        cont.Last_Case_Number_Solved__c = contactIdToCaseNumberMap.get(cont.Id);
    }
    update contactsToUpdate;
}
```